# Vue.js combining objects at certain property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

New to vue and need a bit of help...

I have two arrays of object being returned from firestore, athletes and activities.

Activities has an athlete_id

I am listing all the activities in a v-for, but need to access some of the athlete data for each activity.

What/Where is the best place to add this in a vue component?

I did it with a method, but that seems like a bad way of doing it because there are multiple calls for the activity athlete and it would be having to perform the find each time?

rough sample.

```
<template>
<div class="todays-rides">
    <div class="ride" v-for="activity in activities" :key="activity.activity_id">
        <img :src="activityAthlete(activity.athlete_id).profile>
        <div class="name">
            {{activityAthlete(activity.athlete_id).firstname}}{{activityAthlete(activity.athlete_id).lastname}}
        </div>
        <div class="activity-data">
            .....
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</template>    

<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
        activities: [],
        athletes: []
    }
},

firestore() {
    return {
        activities: db.collection('activities')
        athletes: db.collection('athletes')
    }
},

methods: {
    activityAthlete(id) {
        const athlete = this.athletes.find(o => o.athlete_id === id)
        return athlete
    }
}
...
```

The above does work, but it also throws a Type Error: "Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined.

Comment: your `activityAthlete` most likely has no `.profile`

Comment: You get `undefined` because your `activityAthlete(id)` returns `undefined` which means it is not finding an athlete with the given `athlete_id`.

Comment: Yes you are right, `activityAthlete(id)` was returning `undefined` but only for 1 call. The very first one. But everything is rendering correctly... That athlete's profile renders as it should.

Comment: Is everything working correctly now?

Comment: No. I am still getting the error, even though everything is rendering correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `computed` property to return an object that combines `athletes` and `activity`. Something like:

```
computed:{
    combined(){
        return this.activities.map(a=>{
            a['athlete'] = this.activityAthleted(a.athlete_id)
            return a
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something similar base on your suggestion. Thank you!